# Do there exist types of numbers /algebras where roots to Polynomials of higher degree can be solved?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, soft-question, algorithms

I have heard about Galois' and Abel's famous discovery that the fifth (and higher) order polynomial equations in real coefficients can not be systematically solved with a finite number of the operations $+,-,\times, /,\sqrt{\cdot}$

But what about other types of numbers for roots and coefficients than reals and complex numbers? Do there exist types of numbers where it is possible or even easy to solve polynomial equations of arbitrarly high order in finite number of steps?

Comment: In the finite field $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, any root of a polynomial can be expressed using "$1$" and "$+$." :P

Comment: @NoahSchweber, I would have said much the same thing.